# How to calculate the centroid of a simple shape but rotated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Question:

Locate the centroid $y$ for the cross-sectional area of
the angle.

[image]

I tried to use four triangles, two of them are the bigger ones $(a+t)$ and two of them are the smaller ones $(a-t)$. I then used the idea of proportionality and Pythagoras, but I am now lost on the algebra. Is there a nicer way of doing this like using rotation? I am thinking finding the centroid normally and apply some rotational matrix to the values. Is this even feasible or am I just complicating things? I did it in an arduous way and still didn't get the result. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks -Sarah

PS:

Answer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrix is overkill here. Simple geometric reasoning helps.

If you add a dotted square to L-shape, you will get a bigger square. Thus, if you put a pivot at $O_2$, then the small square (with CoM at distance $O_1O_2$) would be balanced by L-shape (with CoM at distance $O_2C$). Can you know find the distance $\bar y$ from the top right corner to $C$?

[image]